# How to Find and delete DataRow in Datatable asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

```
string s = "primaryKeyValue";
DataRow foundRow = dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"].Rows.Find(s);

if (foundRow != null) 
{
    foreach(DataRow r in dataTable)
    {
        if(r == foundRow)
           r.Delete();
    }
}
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

dataTable and dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"] are different table.
dataTable is a clone of dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"]

this code not working..If anyone know how to "find and delete row in datatable" let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you need to do AcceptChanes on dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"].AcceptChanges() not on the dataTable.AcceptChanges();

Comment: What about `foundRow.Delete(); dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"].AcceptChanges();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` instead of returning all records to `delete` the data.  You already know which row to delete.

***I think that you have deleted one record directly from Pk, this code is more performant.***

> You must be set PK on Table
>
> ```
> ds.Tables["AnyTable"].PrimaryKey = new[] { dt.Columns["YourPKcolumn"] };
> ```

```
        DataRow dr =  ds.Tables["AnyTable"].Rows.Find(PrimaryKeyValue); 
        int idx =  dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(idx);
        ds.Tables["AnyTable"].AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
var datatable = new DataTable(); // take your datatable
string s = "primaryKeyValue";
DataRow[] row = datatable.Select("name='" + s + "'");
for (int i = row.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    datatable.Rows.Remove(row[i]);
}
datatable.AcceptChanges();
```